# 2 dots appears at once in slick carousel on touch devices

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I'm using slick slider for image carousel. On touch devices i can select two dots at the same time, when animation is haven't done yet. How can i fix this ?
http://prntscr.com/m0ja4j

i have tried this (but without expected results):

```
.slick-dots li button:focus:before {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:focus:before {
    opacity: .75;
    color: #000;
}
```

link on not worked solutions https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2651,
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1945

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a bit more of your code, because it could be many factors coursing this issues. 
Maybe a link to where it is possible to play around and see the error, because an image do not tell anything regarding what is coursing the problem.

And are you using the latest version off Jquery and Slick slider, if not try update them.

And the links you provides, is errors from 2016, and should been fix by now.

Answer (score 0):

Use touchpunch.js for the touch devices. I think it will help u.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

Add this in your html file.